# Pass parameters to new process in PHP

Tags: php, process

I can't seem to use system() to create a long lasting, forked process: (yes, params are OK)

```
$args = "/code/perl/test/run $a $n $m $s $c &";
system($args);
```

But, on the flipside this code DOES work, but it doesn't have parameters:

```
system("/code/perl/test/reset &");
```

So, the problem? My C program "run" is instantly killed with the finishing of the PHP script from the HTTP request.

I have tried using the at daemon to create the process using a seperate parent process, but with no success. www-data was removed from /etc/at.deny

It's worth noting that with the 2nd example I do get program output, but not on the first.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> If a program is started in this fashion, in order for it to continue
>   running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Therefore, if it's ending immediately, it most likely does not appear `run` is being ran.  Try sending the output to a different file.  Try:  `exec("/bin/echo $a $n $m $s $c > /tmp/echo &");` to start diagnostics.

After that, I would check for safe_mode and try `escapeshellcmd`.  As a last resort, try the backtick `` ` `` operator.

Comment: "run" is most definitely being ran. The problem is, PHP or something else is ending it, where the task should be allowed to continue.

Comment: Are you on a host which does not allow background tasks or are you in an environment where that is not controlled?

Comment: No. This is my own VPS with full root access. As a more evasive workaround, I've coded an one which requires a seperate daemon to be ran.. hopefully I don't forget to run it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of the PHP script finishing, then killing all child processes attached to it.

If the "at" workaround doesn't work (where you use atd to schedule it for "now"), like it didn't for me, you may have to code a workaround. My workaround just put the command in a file in /tmp/ and then I had my daemon's code execute the commands in the file,  then truncated it.